# Facebook login error in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, facebook-login, google-signin

Controller:

```
public function login()
{
    $userData = array();
    if($this->facebook->is_authenticated())
    {
        $userProfile = $this->facebook->request('get', '/me?fields=id,first_name,last_name,email');
        $userData['oauth_provider'] = 'facebook';
        $userData['oauth_uid'] = $userProfile['id'];
        $userData['firstname'] = $userProfile['first_name'];
        $userData['lastname'] = $userProfile['last_name'];
        $userData['email'] = $userProfile['email'];
        $userData['password'] = rand();
        $userID = $this->user->checkUser($userData);
        if(!empty($userID))
        {
            $data['userData'] = $userData;
            $this->session->set_userdata('userData',$userData);
        } 
        else 
        {
            $data['userData'] = array();
        }
        $data['logoutUrl'] = $this->facebook->logout_url();
    }
    else
    {
        $fbuser = '';
        $data['authUrl'] =  $this->facebook->login_url();
    }



    if($this->session->userdata('loggedIn') == true)
    {
        redirect('test/profile');
    }
    if(isset($_GET['code']))
    {
        $this->google->getAuthenticate();
        $gpInfo = $this->google->getUserInfo();
        $userData['oauth_provider'] = 'google';
        $userData['oauth_uid']      = $gpInfo['id'];
        $userData['firstname']  = $gpInfo['given_name'];
        $userData['lastname']       = $gpInfo['family_name'];
        $userData['email']          = $gpInfo['email'];
        $userData['password'] = rand();
        $userID = $this->user->checkUser($userData);
        $this->session->set_userdata('loggedIn', true);
        $this->session->set_userdata('userData', $userData);
        redirect('test/profile');
    } 
    $data['loginURL'] = $this->google->loginURL();

    $data['student_id'] = $this->session->userdata('student_id');
    $this->load->view('header-inside',$data);
    $this->load->view('login',$data);
}
```

In this code I have create facebook login and google login on same page i.e. login.php where google login work perfectly and facebook login also working but it gives some error like when I have login with facebook. It will show some error like:

```
Type: Google_AuthException

Message: Error fetching OAuth2 access token, message: 'invalid_grant'
```

I don't know why. So, How can I fix this problem ? Please help me.

Thank you

Comment: I have this issue too, but it's from google api, not facebook. I'd suggest to separate this two and check again for each function.

Comment: error in google auth, the access token is not found

Answer (score 0):

separate the logic of google authentication and Facebook authentication , this variable get set when you try to authenticate with Facebook $_GET['code'] due to which it entre the the google authentication code and it gives the error **Message: Error fetching OAuth2 access token, message: 'invalid_grant'**